# Replace unintended deletion of new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found a strange behavior with replace and regular expressions that I can not explain. I have a trim function that removes spaces from the start and end of each line of a text:

```
function trim(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/igm, '');
}
```

But when the text is multi-lined with \r\n instead of \n It also removes the new lines:

```
console.log(trim('A string \n- with several \n- lines'))
// A string\n- with several\n- lines
console.log(trim('A string \r\n- with several \r\n- lines'))
// A string- with several- lines
```

Someone can tell me if this is expected behavior that I don't understand or just one of the warts of JavaScript?

EDIT: I don't need to 'fix' the code, I could do it with split + map + trim:

```
'A string \r\n- with several \r\n- lines'.split('\r\n').map(x => x.trim()).join('\r\n')
```

I am just curious about the different behaviour in the two examples.
If I use match instead of replace I get this:

```
'A string \r\n- with several \r\n- lines'.match(/^\s+|\s+$/igm)
Array(4) [ " \r", "\n", " \r", "\n" ]
'A string \n- with several \n- lines'.match(/^\s+|\s+$/igm)
Array [ " ", " " ]
```

WAT?

Comment: why are you recreating the trim() function if it already exists?

Comment: javascripts' native trim() also removes tabs and is not multiline, I want to remove the extra espaces in each line but not the new line characters or tabs, it doesn't do exactly what I need and the function is short enough that it should be easy...

Comment: I can't help you with regexes since I don't really understand them myself but you can test them here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Your regex says "at the beginning of a line match one or more of a whitespace character OR one or more of a whitespace character at the end of a line". Neither of your examples will match.

Comment: '\s' will match all White spae, which includes Newlines. Simply change to a Space ' '.

Comment: @PoulBak Oh thanks for the insight, I thought that '\s' was just a clearer way to write ' ' inside a regex, but it isn't, A LOT of things match \s (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space) but I still don't see why it works in the first example

Answer (score 2):

Change `igm` to `ig`. The problem is the modifier `m` (multiple lines).

Comment: But If I change the modifier it will only remove the spaces at the beginning and end of the entire text, not in each line. I want to know why it removes the new lines in the second example, I don't need a hack, I could do it with map and trim